# Groovy methodMissing not invoked with no arguments

Tags: groovy

I am using a set of Groovy wrapper classes for accessing MongoDB. An example which works is:

```
MyDB db = MyDB.getInstance("testdb")
DBResult res = db.users.find([:])
```

When "db.users" is invoked, methodMissing returns an instance of a CollectionAccessor class, which is configured to access the "users" collection. When find() is invoked, CollectionAccessor's methodMissing invokes find on the underlying Mongo DBCollection, and performs other useful functions such as converting Map arguments to the required BasicDBObject type. Likewise, the DBResult stores, interprets, and processes things like Mongo Write Results, cursors, and objects returned via the CollectionAccessor.

This all works fine, however, I discovered when executing a test case that when invoking it with no arguments, like:

```
DBResult res = db.users.find()
```

the CollectionAccessor's methodMissing is NEVER called for "find". An instance of CollectionAccessor gets returned, and an exception gets thrown because an attempt is made to assign it to the DBResult class. I traced it in the debugger and indeed see that CollectionAccessor's methodMissing for "find" is only invoked when passing the empty Map parameter. Any ideas why this is occurring? Using Groovy 2.3.6.

Answer (score 0):

`DefaultGroovyMethods` injected in all objects defines already `find()`.  You have to override it.

http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#find%28java.lang.Object%29

> `public static Object find(Object self)`
>
> Finds the first item matching the `IDENTITY` Closure (i.e. matching Groovy truth).

About `DefaultGroovyMethods`:

> This class defines new groovy methods which appear on normal JDK classes inside the Groovy environment. Static methods are used with the first parameter being the destination class, i.e. `public static String reverse(String self)` provides a `reverse()` method for `String`.

Comment: Thanks! I checked GroovyObject to make sure that wasn't the case but missed the default methods.